# Need help expanding an error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, cucumber

I need to expand an error message. I am running a Cucumber test on Mac and getting an error message... with an ellipses instead of relevant details. Can someone tell me, the probably easy way, to get the whole error message instead of this:

```
Command failed with status (1): [bundle exec /Users/sshea4/.rvm/rubies/ree-...]
```

Comment: Which Cucumber formatter are you using?

Comment: Are you running Cucumber directly on the command line?  This looks very similar to what we see once it's gone through Rake and TeamCity (in which case the real error is usually buried somewhere in the full build log)

Comment: @JonM I am running from command line and do not see anything in the Dev log (in Dev environment) or the Cucumber log.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I inherited this and this is my first time using Cucumber so how would I find the formatter?

Comment: Running cucumber with the `--backtrace` switch might give you a bit more information, could you try that and post any extra output with your answer?

Comment: Grrr... it was user error... I was doing `rake cucumber...` instead of just `cucumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a silly thing but I figured I should answer this... cucumber is not a rake task. It is run by doing `cucumber` and not `rake cucumber`